# _context.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate); entity Id error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public async Task<bool> Update(T toUpdate, int Id)
{
    T? tmp = await _entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => _context.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate));
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Book.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.'

Comment: а что тут не понятно? Как Вы думаете почему это происходит?

Comment: Скорее всего в сущности toUpdate который вы пытаетесь сохранить содержит toUpdate.id == 0 или toUpdate.id != id из Update(T toUpdate, int Id), если toUpdate.id == 0, то делайте toUpdate.id = id из Update(T toUpdate, int Id), если у toUpdate.id != 0 и toUpdate.id != id из Update(T toUpdate, int Id), то косяк где-то в вашем коде, т.к. id объекта который вы хотите поменять отличается от id из метода, если id совпадают, то проблема скорее всего в связанных сущностях, в других случаях это тоже следует уччитывать.